# closer to markets

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the exact meaning of "closer to markets" in the following passage? It is about resumption of activities in an old inactive refinery.

> Operation of refinery will probably take some time and then at reduced thru-put due enlarged modern facilities **closer to markets** and obsolescence of old plant.

Comment: I edited your question. Is that how you want it to be? If you don't like it, you can roll back or re-edit your post.

Comment: closer to markets means the modern plant is closer to the points of sale.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the author's telegraphese:

> Operation of [the] refinery will probably take some time and then at reduced throughput due to [competition from] enlarged modern facilities closer to markets and [to] obsolescence of old plant.

This refinery (presumably an oil refinery) competes with other facilities which besides being larger and newer also lie closer to the points at which purchasers take delivery. In consequence, it costs these competitors less to bring their oil to market.